# how to many class share 1 css method in CSS

Tags: css

I try put

```
.dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua,dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass,dxdpLoadingPanel
{
    z-index:999;
}
```

AND

```
.dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua .dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass .dxdpLoadingPanel
{
    z-index:999;
}
```

But cannot function.How to many class or id share 1 method?

Comment: You forgot the dots after the commas in the first example.

Comment: And the first one is correct when you add commas (as Jon suggested).

Comment: your first one cannot work, because you have for the last 2 classes no dot(.) before the classnames. The second one is only for the class "dxdpLoadingPanel" and only when it is child of  dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass and dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS, class selectors are always prefixed with `.`s. To apply the same set of rules on multiple selectors, separate the selectors with commas:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
    /*Making stuff look pretty*/
}
```

However, you can't write that as `.class1, class2, class3` -- you have to use the `.` with every selector. `.class1, class2, class3` selects elements with `class = "class1"`, and elements with **tagname** `class2` or `class3`, hence why your first example isn't working.

**Note:** you can use multiple selectors of different types as well:

```
.class1, #id1, div {
     /*Very fancy*/
}
```

In the example above, `#id1` selects the element with id = "id1" and `div` selects all `div` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the first one but include the full stops to identify the class as so:

```
.dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua, .dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass, .dxdpLoadingPanel
{
    z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**There can be as many as you want.**

but In your case you have `wrong syntax` in your selector you should `.` to indicate the class and `,` to sepreate the classes

**First Selector**

```
.dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua, .dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass, .dxdpLoadingPanel
{
    z-index:999;
}
```

this will apply css to **all the 3 classes**

- dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua
- dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass
- dxdpLoadingPanel

**Second selector**

```
.dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua .dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass .dxdpLoadingPanel
{
    z-index:999;
}
```

this will apply css to the only  **dxdpLoadingPanel** class which is child of dxdpLoadingPanel_BlackGlass  which is child of  dxdpLoadingPanel_Aqua